# Making Prism JS to work in Rails 7 with Import Maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, initialization, prism, import-maps

I would like to use [Prism](https://prismjs.com/) in my Rails 7 project to highlight code in specific pages.

To make that:

1. I [downloaded](https://prismjs.com/download.html) the Development version of Prism for Markup + HTML + ..., CSS, C-like, and JavaScript languages, and with all the available plugins.
2. I imported the Prism library in Rails 7 by following the [Path 2: Download css and js files into your vendor folder](https://eagerworks.com/blog/import-maps-in-rails-7) blog post.

Now, in my Rails project I've these files:

```
project
> vendor
  > javascript
    > prism.js
  > stylesheet
    > prism.css
```

I also changed relevant files by adding Prism-related references:

```
# config/importmap.rb
pin 'prism', to: 'prism.js'

# app/javascript/application.js
import 'prism'

# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import 'stylesheet/prism';
```

To verify code highlighting, in a my test.html.erb template file I added the following:

```
<pre><code class="language-css line-numbers">
  p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
</code></pre>
```

But when I render that page then in the browser console I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Prism.languages.css.selector.inside is undefined*.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: select "CSS Extras" when downloading

Comment: I wrote a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/prism-rails) and just released the latest version of prism.js you can also use it that way